# On the convergence of infinite sum of a hypergeometric function resulted from a nested sum

Tags: time-series, probability, mathematical-statistics, calculus

I am interested in finding the CDF of the sum $U=\sum_{i=0}^N U_i$ where:
$$F_{U_i}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {2(-1)^nR^{k\alpha+n\alpha}x^{k+n}}{\Gamma(k)n!\theta^{k+n}(k+n)(k\alpha+n\alpha+2)}$$ 
where $k$ and $\theta$ are a positive real number and $\alpha$ is positive integer.
Obviously, I need to get the Laplace transform of the above and raise to power $N$. Before that, I did some simplifications, $y=xR^\alpha/\theta$, $C=\frac{2}{\Gamma(k)}$, and $G(n)=\frac{(-1)^n\Gamma(k+n+1)}{n!(k+n)(k\alpha+n\alpha+2)}$, so the Laplace transform becomes: 
$$\mathcal{L}(F_{U_i})=C\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{G(n)}{s^{k+n+1}}$$
raise the above to power $N$ and representing the product of sum in terms of sums of products we have: 
$$\mathcal{L}(F_{U})=C^N\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty...\sum_{n_N=0}^\infty \frac{G(n_1)...G(n_N)}{s^{kN+n_1+...+n_N+N}}$$
Applying inverse Laplace transform: 
$$F_U(y)=C^N\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty...\sum_{n_N=0}^\infty \frac{G(n_1)...G(n_N)y^{kN+n_1+...+n_N+N-1}}{\Gamma(kN+n_1+...+n_N+N)}$$

This means I need to find sum of nested sums. To do that, I simplified it by making $N=2$ and now the sums become:

$$\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+n_1+1)(-y)^{n_1}}{n_1!(k+n_1)(k\alpha+n_1\alpha+2)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+n+1)(-y)^n}{\Gamma(kN+n_1+n+N)n!(k+n)(k\alpha+n\alpha+2)}$$

Note that I took $y^{kN+N-1}$ out of the sums. My approach is to fix $n_1$and vary $n$ and solve for the inner sum which converges to: 
$$\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{k(k\alpha+2)\Gamma(kN+n_1+N)}{}_2F_2(k,k+\frac{2}{\alpha}; kN+n_1+N, k+\frac{2}{\alpha}+1; -y)$$
After that we vary $n_1$ and take the constant term out of the outer summation: 
$$\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{k(k\alpha+2)}\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+n_1+1){}_2F_2(k,k+2/\alpha; kN+n_1+N, k+2/\alpha+1; -y)(-y)^{n_1}}{\Gamma(kN+n_1+N)n_1!(k+n_1)(k\alpha+n_1\alpha+2)}$$
Now I am looking for ways to see if the above summation converges, I tried Wolfram it says ratio test is inconclusive. Does that mean the sum diverge? 
Actually the problem is in the term $\Gamma(kN+n_1+n+1)$ in the denominator of the inner sum in the 4th equation. If I were able to take the $n_1$ variable out of the inner sum it would solve everything. 
Is there anyone can tell whether the sums in the 4th or 5th equation converge? If yes, what would be the sums? If no, is there anyway to approximate the sum?

Comment: Often one can find alternative solutions by knowing what problem such an expression originally solves.  Brute-force attack on such sums otherwise is unpalatable and unlikely to inspire many readers to look for a solution.

Comment: @whuber I have updated my question.